# Excel 2007 simple copy and paste vba not working in excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2016, vba

I've put together what is an audit workbook which is supposed to copy and paste some hidden cells to a data storage sheet that is hidden the collective data in the hidden sheet is then used for KPI reports.

The problem is that I've put it together in Excel 2007, in which it works perfectly but now it needs to be used in Excel 2016.

I'm running the macro from a button, if the button is pressed  it copies the data and selects the field in the hidden sheet but doesn't paste, no error dialogues either.

When I step  through the code in the vba editor it works fine, but not from the button despite the button being linked to the code. I'm a bit lost or what to do as I don't know how to correct the code.

Here's the code:

```
Sub CopyPhoneAuditToDB()
'
'
' Copy Phone Audit To DB

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Data Phone").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Data Phone").Unprotect
    Range("E49:T49").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data Phone").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    Sheets("Phone Audit").Select
    Range("H5:J5").Select
    Sheets("Data Phone").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: You `.Activate` sheets while a `.Range` gets selected. Any deviation thereof can result in errors (in earlier versions of Excel). So, it should be `Range("E49:T49").Select` and `Sheets("Data Phone").Activate`.

Comment: Hi Ralph, I forgot to take that out of the code, I tried .Activate as an alternative but .Select doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between the two please?

Comment: I've been using `.Select` in Excel for sheets for years, I even just tested `Sheets("Phone Audit").Activate` on it's own and it works. I implemented your suggestions but the code performs the same.

Comment: I know that `.Select` worked for years. But just in recent versions of Excel it is known to cause problems and since your post is `why is something working in Excel 2007 but not in Excel 2016` Hence, I proposed this change. Other than that you code is working fine in my Excel 2016 64-bit.

Comment: Fair point, I'll keep that in mind. The workbook is originally from Excel 2007. The other thing that's a consideration is that the cells it's trying to copy are in a hidden row. I've used `Rows("48:49").EntireRow.Hidden = True/False` to see if that made a difference but it didn't.

Comment: Are you copying from the sheet `Data Phone` to the sheet `Phone Audit` or is it the inverse?

Comment: The inverse, the button to run this code is on the `Phone Audit` sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this works for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPhoneAuditToDB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Data Phone")
    .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    .Unprotect
    Sheets("Phone Audit").Range("E49:T49").Copy
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .Protect
End With

With Sheets("Phone Audit")
    .Activate
    .Range("H5:J5").Select
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help, I've now fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, where `Sheets("Data Phone").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Data Phone").Unprotect` were taking focus away from the sheet it was run from `Phone Audit` it was more than likely copying E49:T49 from the `Data Phone` sheet.

See the following code that includes a new line to bring focus back to the `Phone Audit` sheet.

```
Sub CopyPhoneAuditToDB()
'
'
' Copy Phone Audit To DB

'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Data Phone").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Data Phone").Unprotect
    Sheets("Phone Audit").Activate '***************
    Range("E49:T49").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data Phone").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    Sheets("Phone Audit").Activate
    Range("H5:J5").Select
    Sheets("Data Phone").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Cheers

John